# What are the advantages of fish shell?

Tags: shell

What are the advantages of fish shell?

Comment: <doctor who> It's the fish.   They like the singing. </doctor who>

Comment: This is highly opinionated, and really isn't ServerFault material.  Use "the Google" for things like this.

Comment: The food at this xmas party is pretty lame. I could really go for some shellfish instead... Oh? What's that? Fish shell? Come on now, `/usr/bin/fish`? A shell that purports to be friendly *and* interactive? You must be kidding.

Comment: Sorry guys, as a linux newbie, i tried to check the http://www.fishshell.org/ site to get more information, after i read here that it would be more userfriendly. my intend was to get more info on what features it provide since the information i found via google was not very helpful. anyway now i test it on my own :)

Comment: When a bare Google search fails, usually a second good place to check is Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking for that the FAQ, documentation, or the person who said "fish shell is awesome" hasn't told you?

(In other words, this is a question you should research yourself to see if it meets your needs...)